# Random string in Django template

Tags: django, templates, random-access

Is there any way to have a random string in a Django template?

I would like to have multiple strings displaying randomly like:

```
{% here generate random number rnd ?%}

{% if rnd == 1 %}
  {% trans "hello my name is john" %}
{% endif %}

{% if rnd == 2 %}
  {% trans "hello my name is bill" %}
{% endif %}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for answer but my case needed something more specific as it was in the base template (which I forgot to mention sorry ). So after crawling Google and some docs I fall on context processor article which did the job, I found it a little bit "heavy" anyway just for generating a random number...

here is the blog page : http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

Template tag did not the trick (or I did not find how) as it return a tag that cannot be translated as I remember (see blocktrans doc)

I did not find a way to generate a number for the base view (is there any?) and if there is a way better than context process I'd be glad to have some info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to have a tag that generates random strings from some table containing strings. See this Django snippet:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/286/:

```
# model
class Quote(models.Model):
  quote = models.TextField(help_text="Enter the quote")
  by = models.CharField(maxlength=30, help_text="Enter the quote author")
  slug = models.SlugField(prepopulate_from=("by", "quote"), maxlength=25)
  def __str__(self):
    return (self.quote)

# template tag
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from website.quotes.models import Quote

@register.simple_tag
def random_quote():
  """
  Returns a random quote
  """
  quote = Quote.objects.order_by('?')[0]

  return str(quote)
```

Answer (score 25):

Instead of using `if-else` blocks, passing a list of strings to your template and using `random` filter seems better

In your view:

```
my_strings = ['string1', 'string2', ...]
...
return render_to_response('some.html', {'my_strings':my_strings})
```

And in your template:

```
{{ my_strings|random }}
```

[Here is the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#random).

Comment: You can also add this to context_processors and have it available globally. Good tip

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like that:

```
{# set either "1" or "2" to rnd, "12"|make_list outputs the list [u"1", u"2"] #}
{# and random chooses one item randomly out of this list #}

{% with rnd="12"|make_list|random %}
    {% if rnd == "1" %}
        {% trans "hello my name is john" %}
    {% elif rnd == "2" %}
        {% trans "hello my name is bill" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Look at the "Built-in template tags and filters" documentation for more info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: I suppose this is only limited by the number of letters in unicode, but that `with` statement is going to get really weird really quickly. It's worth it though just so we can have the statement `{% elif rnd == "" %}`

Comment: Looking at this makes me miss Jinja so much : ( Thank you, sir

Answer (score 0):

You should write a custom template tag, see this one (with close functionality) as an example: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/150/, but if it is not critical, to array of lines in the template, I would rather generete this random string in view.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to include random template and have it available globally :

in context_processors:

```
def sample(request):
  my_strings = ['string1', 'string2', ...]
  return {banners: my_stirngs}
```

in tempale (giving that your includes are in 'inc' folder ):

```
  {% with banners|random as template %}
    {% include 'inc/'|add:template %}
  {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a template:

```
{% random_number as rnd %}
The best 6 digits (by default) random number is: {{ rnd }}

{% random_number 9 as rnd9 %}
The best 9 digit random number is: {{ rnd9 }}
```

In markup.py:

```
@register.assignment_tag()
def random_number(length=6):
    from random import randint
    return randint(10**(length-1), (10**(length)-1))
```

Taken from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2984/