# How to iterate models.objects.all() in django template when html tags classes are different

Tags: python, html, css, django

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField('Descriptiom')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), editable=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by("-pub_date")[:10]
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'articles': articles}
```

home.html
{% load static %}

```
    <hr class="line2">
      <a class="other_articles">Другие статьи</a>
      {% for art in articles %}
        <rect class="rectangle2_1">
            <img src="{{ art.img.url }}" id="rect_img">
            <a id="rect_date">{{ art.pub_date }}</a>
            <p href="#" id="rect_title">{{ art.title }}</p>
        </rect>
        <rect class="rectangle2_2">
          <img src="{{ art.img.url }}" id="rect_img">
          <a id="rect_date">{{ art.pub_date }}</a>
          <p href="#" id="rect_title">{{ art.title }}</p>
        </rect>
        <rect class="rectangle2_3">
            <img src="{{ art.img.url }}" id="rect_img">
            <a id="rect_date">{{ art.pub_date }}</a>
            <p href="#" id="rect_title">{{ art.title }}</p>
        </rect>
      {% endfor %}
```

Cant iterate through my queryset "articles" in django template, because html  classes
are different.
I know the method:

```
{% for art in articles %}
<rect....>art.title</rect>
{% endfor %}
```

but it doesn't work for current situation

Comment: How you define which class should be used for each record?

Comment: It doesn't matter, classes differ only in their position.
I have 10 records and 10 classes(with different positions). They could be in random order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it with index `articles.0`, `articles.1`... without for.

```
<rect class="rectangle2_1">
    <img src="{{ articles.0.img.url }}" id="rect_img">
    <a id="rect_date">{{ articles.0.pub_date }}</a>
    <p href="#" id="rect_title">{{ articles.0.title }}</p>
</rect>
<rect class="rectangle2_2">
  <img src="{{ articles.1.img.url }}" id="rect_img">
  <a id="rect_date">{{ articles.1.pub_date }}</a>
  <p href="#" id="rect_title">{{ articles.1.title }}</p>
</rect>
<rect class="rectangle2_3">
    <img src="{{ articles.2.img.url }}" id="rect_img">
    <a id="rect_date">{{ articles.2.pub_date }}</a>
    <p href="#" id="rect_title">{{ articles.title }}</p>
</rect>
```

Don't forget to add check that index exist.

Comment: Thank you weAreStarDust! For now it solved my problem.
But what can i do if there are many classes and many records, for future?

Comment: @RafoSardaryan, Glad to hear, accept the answer if it was useful. About many classes/records, hard to suggest, when i don't know the rules of your rectangles composition, but you can try use for loop for all records and get random class of rectangle for each iteration, look here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861193/12613186/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861193/12613186/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to iterate over a queryset.

One possible approach would be convert the queryset to a list first and then iterate over the list:

```
articles = Article.objects.all().order_by("-pub_date")[:10]
list = []
for item in articles.iterator():
    list.append(item)
```

And then in your html:

```
{% for art in list %}
<p>art<p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My question is about something else. When I iterate in the template, the same entry is output in all three tags with different classes